# Show DataGrid rows in Stimulsoft report Same order as DataGrid

Tags: c#, gridview, datatable, stimulsoft

When I pass gridview's datasource to stimulsoft report
changing sort of rows and I don't want that
I want to show same as gridview in form,
and I dont want to use grouping in report
is there a solution ?

I tried any properties of report databand